# My Code Working in windows but the same code running in linux giving error

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Its a **tick box**, finding element by xpath and trying to select that element by xpath and click on that, which is working in windows but same is not working in linux

Tried it in windows but not able to find solution for linux

```
actual_site = driver.find_element_by_link_text("filmgrapevine.com - 
(14221)").click()  #live
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("square-300x250")  # Getting 
unable to find element error
elem.click()
submit = driver.find_element_by_id("PageAds").click()
```

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("square-300x250") 
Getting unable to find element error

I tried using xpath, selector various solutions found on stackoverflow but no result
anyone can help me out?
Even tried on chrome driver and gecko driver in linux not working

Comment: Could you post the traceback for the "unable to find element" error? If you open a browser on your Linux machine, are you able to manually find the element with that ID?